# Ajax script writing

Tags: php, ajax

I have this code for example

```html
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['goose'])){
echo '<div>goose</div>';
}
?>
```

```html
  <form action="goose.php" method="POST">
    <input type="submit" name="goose" />
    </form>
```

How can I write something like this but in AJAX? I don't know this language.

Comment: Is this homework? AJAX is not a language but a system to send your javascript data for example to a php file for processing, like storing in a database.

Comment: yea... it is a homework

Comment: Do a Google Search for PHP Ajax

Comment: oh thanks that s a nice answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [jQuery](https://jquery.com/).

```
$.ajax({  //  begins our async AJAX request
  type: "POST",  //  defining as POST
  url: "goose.php",  //  page to request data from
  data: ["goose":$("input[name=goose]").val()],  //  define POST values
  success: function(output){
    alert(output);
  },
  error: //do something else
});
```

---

Because we have set the type to `POST` our data will need to be in the form of an associative array with `"goose"` being equivalent to `$_POST["goose"]`.

```
  data: ["goose":$("input[name=goose]").val()],
```

---

The `success` is what will happen if the data is able to be sent correctly with `output` being what is returned. In our case `output` = `<div>goose</div>`.

```
  success: function(output){
    alert(output);
  }
```

---

`error` can also have a function but here you will want to tell the script what do do if say `goose.php` is un-reachable.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 1):

No need for extra frameworks. Just use fetch api.

```
<form action="goose.php" method="POST" onsubmit="submit(event, this)">
  <input type="submit" name="goose" />
</form>
```

Javascript:

```
function submit(event, form) {
  event.preventDefault();

  fetch(form.action,{
    method: 'post', 
    body: new FormData(form)
  }).then((data) => {
    console.log(data);
  });
}
```